# To find the last occurrence of particular value and replace certain values occurs after the particular last occurrence value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am new to coding. I want a logic that works on csv file. Lets say I am having a dataframe with a column name "label" and I wanted to have an output look like column "expected label".

```
print (df)
   label
0      A
1      B
2      C
3      A
4      B
5      C
6      A
7      B
8      C
9      B
10     C
```

[image]

I need to find the last occurrence of the value "A" and replace other values (in this case "B" & "C" with "H") occurs only after the last occurrence. This is my code and don't know how to proceed after that.

```
last=df['labels']
max(loc for loc, val in enumerate(last) if val == 'A')
```

This gets me the last positional occurrence of "A". What I need is how to replace values after finding the last occurrence like I mentioned in the "expected label" column. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Where is your code, what is the problem you got with it? SO does not code for you. [ask] and [mre] apply when asking else you risk getting down and close-voted..

Comment: I read that How to Ask link. But still I need to learn. thank you @PatrickArtner for pointing out. This is my code and don't know how to proceed after that. last=df['labels']; max(loc for loc, val in enumerate(last) if val == 'A'); This gets me the last positional occurrence of "A". What I need is how to replace values after finding the last occurrence like I mentioned in the "expected label" column.

Comment: If you're new to Python I suggest that you don't try working with dataframes (which I *think* you're doing). Better to see how you would do this using Python primitives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with swapped order in `iloc[::-1]` for `False` for all values after last `A` and set values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Expected'] = df['label'].where(df['label'].eq('A').iloc[::-1].cummax(), 
                                   df['label'].replace(to_replace =["B", "C"], value ="H"))
print (df)
   label Expected
0      A        A
1      B        B
2      C        C
3      A        A
4      B        B
5      C        C
6      A        A
7      B        H
8      C        H
9      B        H
10     E        E
```

Or:

```
df['Expected'] = df['label'].where(df['label'].eq('A').iloc[::-1].cummax() | 
                                   ~df['label'].isin(['B','C']), 'H')
print (df)
```

Comment: thank you. It's working. what to do when the 11th row got the label "E", and it should not be replace with "H". How to do that @jezrael

Comment: @PallaviC - in another words replace only `B, C` after `A` ?

Comment: yes @jezrael exactly

Comment: This is the change I made to your code. df['Expected'] = df['label'].where(df['label'].eq('A').iloc[::-1].cummax(), df['label'].replace(to_replace =["B", "C"], value ="H")) @jezrael